# Write the PDE $xu_{xx}+u_{yy}=x^2$ in canonical form

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am having trouble getting the transformation right. Let me show my work:

We know $b^2-4ac=-4x$, so if $x>0$ the equation is eliptic. Let's make our substitution:

$\epsilon= -bx+2ay=2xy $

$n= \sqrt{4ac-b^2}x=\sqrt{4x}x=2x^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Notice that $\epsilon_{x}=2y, \epsilon_{y}=2x, n_{x}=3x^{\frac{1}{2}}, n_{y}=0$.
Thus, we have:

$u_{x}=u_{\epsilon}\epsilon_{x}+u_{n}n_{x}=2yu_{\epsilon}+3x^{\frac{1}{2}}u_{n}$

$u_{xx}= D_{\epsilon}[2yu_{\epsilon}+3x^{\frac{1}{2}}u_{n} ] +D_{n}[ 2yu_{\epsilon}+3x^{\frac{1}{2}}u_{n} ] = (2yu_{\epsilon\epsilon}+3x^{\frac{1}{2}}u_{n\epsilon})(2y) + (2yu_{\epsilon n}+3x^{\frac{1}{2}}u_{nn})(3x^\frac{1}{2})=4y^2u_{\epsilon\epsilon}+6x^{\frac{1}{2}} yu_{\epsilon n} + 9x u_{nn}$

$u_{y}=u_{\epsilon}\epsilon_{y}+u_{n}n_{y}=2xu_{\epsilon}$

$u_{yy}= D_{\epsilon}(2x u_{\epsilon})(2x)=4x^2u_{\epsilon\epsilon}$

When I substitute all of these expresions into our PDE I get:
$xu_{xx}+u_{yy}=x^2 = x(4y^2u_{\epsilon\epsilon}+6x^{\frac{1}{2}} yu_{\epsilon n} + 9x u_{nn})+ 
4x^2u_{\epsilon\epsilon}=x^2$

Unfortunately, this is not a proper canonical form. I appreciate it if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I need to complete this exercise as quickly as possible, thank you for help!

Comment: A _very_ similar example is given on the last page [here](https://faculty.uml.edu//spennell/Teaching/PDE/classification.pdf). If you are still having difficulty afterwards, I'll write up an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the transformation $u(x,y)=w(\xi,\eta)$, where $\xi=f(x)$ and $\eta=y$. Then
$$
u_x=w_{\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dx}=w_{\xi}f'(x), \tag{1}
$$
$$
u_{xx}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[w_{\xi}f'(x)]=w_{\xi\xi}[f'(x)]^2+w_{\xi}f''(x), \tag{2}
$$
$$
u_y=w_{\eta},\qquad u_{yy}=w_{\eta\eta}. \tag{3}
$$
Substituting $(1)$-$(3)$ in the PDE $xu_{xx}+u_{yy}=x^2$, we obtain
$$
x[f'(x)]^2w_{\xi\xi}+w_{\eta\eta}+xf''(x)w_{\xi}=x^2. \tag{4}
$$
In order to put $(4)$ in the canonical form of an elliptic PDE, we choose $f(x)$ so that the coefficient of $w_{\xi\xi}$ is $1$:
$$
x[f'(x)]^2=1 \implies f'(x)= x^{-1/2} \implies
\xi=f(x)=2x^{1/2}, \tag{5}
$$
where, for definiteness, we selected the positive branch of the square root. It follows from $(5)$ that $x=\frac{\xi^2}{4}$ and $xf''(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}=-\frac{1}{\xi}$, so we can finally rewrite $(4)$ as
$$
w_{\xi\xi}+w_{\eta\eta}-\frac{1}{\xi}w_{\xi}=\frac{\xi^2}{4}. \tag{6}
$$